# Looking for a way to position block elements in a line, but design falls apart at 25% zoom

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am designing a page, and run into a problem, I can not solve on my own. On zooming out, the items in the header are moving vertically, at 25%, the elements are in completely wrong position.
I am using block display, because i want the menu items to move to the center on zoomout(like on facebook, twitter or here), so inline and inline-block not solving my problem.
Same reason on relative positioning.

Is there another way to achive the same effect instead of relative positioning?

Any ideas how to make it right?

Cheers

Andrew

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen"> </style>
  <title>Layout</title>
  <link href="../Content/LAYOUT.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="menucontainer">
    <div id="wrapper">
            <a href="HTTP://www.google.com" class="LC">
                <p class="L"> </p>
            </a>
            <a href="http://www.idk.com" class="KC">
                <p class="K">Új Kérdés</p>
            </a>
            <a href="http://www.idk.com" class="EC">
                <p class="E">Új Értékelés</p>
            </a>
            <a href="http://www.idk.com" class="MessageC">
                <p class="Message"> </p>
            </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
body { background-color: lightgray;
   margin:0 auto;}

 #menucontainer { 
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
min-height: 45px;
height: 20px;
background: #3f3f3f; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3f3f3f 0%, #000000 91%, #3f3f3f 91%, #33eb31 93%, #33eb31 101%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#3f3f3f), color-stop(91%,#000000), color-stop(91%,#3f3f3f), color-stop(93%,#33eb31), color-stop(101%,#33eb31)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3f3f3f 0%,#000000 91%,#3f3f3f 91%,#33eb31 93%,#33eb31 101%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3f3f3f 0%,#000000 91%,#3f3f3f 91%,#33eb31 93%,#33eb31 101%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3f3f3f 0%,#000000 91%,#3f3f3f 91%,#33eb31 93%,#33eb31 101%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3f3f3f 0%,#000000 91%,#3f3f3f 91%,#33eb31 93%,#33eb31 101%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#3f3f3f', endColorstr='#33eb31',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 12px 4px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.64);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 12px 4px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.64);
box-shadow: 0px 2px 12px 4px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.64);
font-family: Corbel;
z-index: 2;
display: inline-block; }

#wrapper {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 960px;
z-index: -1;
white-space: nowrap;
height: 30px;
max-height: 30px;
display: block;
padding-top:9px;
padding-bottom:10px; }

.LC {
left: 0%;
min-width: 30px;
top: -20px;
max-width:30px;
width:30px;
display: block;
position:relative;
white-space:nowrap;
height:30px;
min-height:30px;
margin-right:20px;
margin-top:2px; }

.L {
background-image: url(/logo.png);
background-size: 30px 30px;
height: 30px;
width: 30px;
min-width: 30px;
max-width: 30px; }

.KC {
left: 7%;
top: -64px;
display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
text-decoration: none;
width:90px;
min-width:90px;
white-space:nowrap;
height:30px; }

.K {
font-family: Arial;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 1.2em;
color: white;
text-decoration:none; }

.K:link {
text-decoration: none; }

.K:visited {
    text-decoration: none; }

.K:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #33eb31; }

.K:active {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none; }

.EC {
left: 20%;
top: -105px;
display: block;
position: relative;
text-decoration: none;
width:110px;
min-width:110px;
white-space:nowrap;
height:30px; }

.E {
position: relative;
font-family: Arial;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 1.2em;
color: white;
min-width: 30px; }

.E:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.E:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.E:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #33eb31;
}

.E:active {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to center the menu elements? This can be done with `display: block; margin: auto;` CSS styling on the container of the menu....

Comment: I am planning to put other elements in the header, but i don't want them to be in the center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be over complicating this a little bit. you shouldn't need to use `position:absolute;`. You should use `ul li` elements for your menu instead. You can set `#wrapper` to the size of your page and use `margin:0px auto` to center it.

Let me know if this looks like what you're trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/gxwxk3zv/